# Integers in calculated fields for MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to query a MySQL database.  The fields that are stored in the database as integers are returned as integers which is as I would expect.  When there is a value calculated in a Stored Procedure it is always returned as longlong, even if I can guarantee that the number will be either 0 or 1.

I need a way to ensure that the result of a calculated field is still returned as an int.

Interestingly, doing the calculation in a view, and then querying that view seems to fix the problem, but it takes an enormous performance hit.

**Edit**

An example of the sorts of procedures I'm trying to use would be:

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE getProjectFinance(IN projectID varchar(30)) 
    BEGIN 
            SELECT  p.projectID as id,
                (Select sum(COALESCE(v.Cost, 0))
                    from variations v
                    where v.projectID = p.projectID) as total
            FROM Projects p
            WHERE p.projectID  = projectID;
    END//
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE getAllProjectsFinance() 
    BEGIN 
            SELECT  p.projectID as id,
                (Select sum(COALESCE(v.Cost, 0))
                    from variations v
                    where v.projectID = p.projectID) as total
            FROM Projects p
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Edit 2**

I've attempted to simplify the problem slightly.  The following SQL command returns a record with a single field (count) which is of type longlong (8 bytes).  I want it to be of type integer (4 bytes)

```
SELECT (Select 1) as count;
```

Using cast as follows doesn't help either:

```
SELECT cast((Select 1) as signed integer) as count;
```

Comment: Since you're talking about returned values, I assume you're talking about stored functions, not procedures. Can you post your store function's definition (`SHOW CREATE FUNCTION function_name` would help)? It should explicitly define its return type.

Comment: Updated, I'm not sure how I explicitly define the return types.

Answer (score 1):

What if you just cast the calculated value?

```
cast((
    Select sum(COALESCE(v.Cost, 0))
    from variations v
    where v.projectID = p.projectID
    ) 
    as integer
) as total
```

Comment: How would I call that?  I get an error saying that I'm using an incorrect number of parameters if I just call that with a projectID?

Comment: If your procedure returns more than one row then I guess you will have to use a function in instead of a procedure. About the error you must pass the output parameter to the procedure as shown in the linked page.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to do it with a function then?  More fundamentally this seems odd though given that the procedures in the question work fine except for the typing.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far @Clodoaldo. unfortunately the code you pasted results in a syntax error.  I tried replacing integer with `signed integer`  But that seems to result in a data type of longlong, which is the problem in the first place.

Comment: No, that's definitely still giving me a type longlong when I use `unsigned integer`

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE FUNCTION name(parameter paramType, .... ) RETURNS returnType` instead of `create procedure ...` you should also use a return clause at the end of the body of your function. For more information look at [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) the common and function specific parts.

Comment: What about when there are multiple records/multiple fields?

Comment: You can return rows or even record sets from a function. Just adapt return type accordingly.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of doing that?  I.e. provide a function that selects a few records from a table, where one of the fields is a calculated int?  Thanks

Comment: There are lots of examples of all sorts of similar, but not identical things, none of them work and solve my problem though so far.